# Android studio 3 build apk comflict with previous apk

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio 2.3 for the development, last week i am completely remove the android studio 2.3 from the system and install the latest android studio 3. The same project imported from android studio 2.3 into android studio 3. the build apk generated using android studio 3 is conflicting with the build apk generated using android studio 2.3. and the db is reset completely erase database. how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the database is a solution for that. I am just copy the .db files for files beside in data/ data / your package name / database/ folder into my computer. Uninstall the old apk and install the latest when generated using android studio 3 gradle version 3, and just copy the previous database files into new one using the android studio 3 device explorer. But its not at all a reliable solution for the problem, but i am using this method for installing the latest update without losing the database